# TypeError: _firebase_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.firestore.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { firestore } from '../firebase/firebase';

const useFirestore = (collection) => {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = firestore.collection(collection)
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        let documents = [];
        snap.forEach(doc => {
          documents.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
        });
        setDocs(documents);
      });

    return () => unsub();
    // this is a cleanup function that react will run when
    // a component using the hook unmounts
  }, [collection]);

  return { docs };
}

export default useFirestore
```

Im trying to use this custom hook i found on a tutorial to access firestore but it keeps giving this error and i cant find anything to fix it.

firebase file looks like this.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
    "this is filled with info I got from firebase just dont want to post it on the internet."
};

const firestore = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export { firestore }
```

Comment: What's in `../firebase/firebase`? What is the `firestore` variable defined as?

Comment: Your exported `firestore` is certainly the wrong thing, but we can't see what it is.

Comment: alright posted the firebase file

Comment: `firebase.initializeApp()` returns a Firebase app. If you want to export the `firestore` API, you need `const firestore = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).firestore()`

Comment: alright thank you it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` returns a FirebaseApp object.  You have to call `firestore()` on that to get the default FirebaseFirestore object.  I suggest that you export the FirebaseApp object:

```
const firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export { firebase }
```

Then import it like this:

```
import { firebase } from '../firebase/firebase';
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

This will let one import make available the entire suite of Firebase products, should you choose to use more than Firestore.